# Find element by child count

Tags: jquery, xpath

Is there a method using jquery or xpath to select an element that has fewer than n children ?

so given:

```
<div id="1" class="parent">
  <div class="child></div>
  <div class="child></div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="parent">
  <div class="child></div>
  <div class="child></div>
  <div class="child></div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="parent">

</div>
```

I would want all the parents with fewer than 3 child divs, id 1 and 3

Comment: there's no one liner that would do it, but yeah this could be done with filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath should select what you want:

```
//div[@class = 'parent' and 3 > count(div)]
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you